# Calculus minimum stationary point

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

Prove using calculus that $f\left(s\right)=\frac{n^{2}}{s}+\frac{1}{t-s}$, $t>s>0$, has a minimum at $s=\frac{nt}{1+n}$.

I differentiated $\frac{n^{2}}{s}$ w/respect to s and got $-\frac{n^{2}}{s^{2}}$, but am not sure how to differentiate $\frac{1}{t-s}$ and would like some guidance on how to continue from there.

Comment: Use the chain rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Think about how to differentiate $\frac{1}{x-1}$. Use the same concept in your question since $t$ is a constant.

Comment: that's way too easy: $-\frac{1}{\left(x-1\right)^{2}}$

Comment: Exactly, so $\frac{1}{t-s}$ is same as $\frac{-1}{s-t}$... So how would you differentiate this? The same way. Try now

Comment: $-\frac{1}{\left(t-s\right)^{2}}$

Comment: Noo... it is $\frac{1}{(t-s)^2}$. It has no negative sign.

Comment: thats what i meant.